# Building an oauth 1 client to interface with another API

Tags: meteor

I've searched a lot for examples of this, but only found bits and pieces and am having trouble piecing them together.

Are there any simple examples for implementing an oauth1 client in meteor so I can talk to an API provider that I want to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accounts UI provides configuration wizards for each of the OAuth login packages :)
There's also a bit more info at: http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-customizing-login